# C++ Only Allow a member variable to be set once

Tags: c++, constants, mutable, const-correctness

It's been a while since I've jumped into C++ but I want to make sure I'm sticking to best practices when I do, including being const-correct.

I'm currently building a library of code for a game framework and I have the following classes (summarised for simplicity):

```
class Screen
{
public:
    Clear();
}
```

and

```
class Game
{
private:
    Screen* screen;

protected:
    const Screen* GetScreen() const;
}
```

I've omitted the rest for brevity but suffice it to say, the `Game` class is responsible for the creation of the `Screen` class instance.  After it is created, it should only be accessed through the `GetScreen()` method.

The idea is, that when creating a new game, I would inherit from this base class, so as an example, during a render loop I would want to clear the screen to redraw the next frame.  Now, in my above definitions, the `Clear()` method is not allowed to be called when using the `GetScreen()` method because it is not `const`.  The clear method would actually change the internal workings of the class (by virtue of the fact that the previously displayed image is cleared) so that is why I left the `const` declaration out of the definition. If I made it `const` then I would have to have some of the inner workings of the `Screen` class as `mutable` but from what I've read, this would not be very const-correct.

So, I have two parts to my question. Should I change `void Clear()` to `void Clear() const` and make parts of the inner workings `mutable`?

Or is the an alternative that would allow me to make the `screen` member of the `Game` class only settable once by the `Game` class so that I can access the non-const member functions during the rest of the program's run time.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like you want `screen` to be a `Screen&` or `Screen* const` instead of `const Screen*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of 'const' is useful to indicate that an object's internal state should not be modifiable.

```
void f(const Object& o)
{
    // 'o' cannot be modified
}
```

The ability to mark a non-static member as `const` allows you to enforce that holders of a `const` reference to the object cannot modify the internal state. For example, in the following scenario, `Object` has an accessor `str` that returns a reference to a internal state, which has both non-const and const overloads:

```
struct Object
{
    // non-const: caller can modify internal state
    std::string& str();

    // const: caller cannot modify internal state
    const std::string& str() const;
};
```

The non-const overload allows modification of internal state, but can be called only on a non-const reference to the object; the const overload does not allow modification of internal state and can be used with both const and non-const object references.

In the scenario you present, `Game` appears to be a monolithic [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object that contains everything in your program. If so, it seems questionable that it would be useful to ever pass a reference to a `Game` - or to an object derived from it - making the distinction between `const Game&` and `Game&` somewhat moot. If this is the case, const-correctness has no utility and you will save yourself a headache if you simply make all members of `Game` non-const.

Comment: I think I will do as you suggest and make members of `Game` non-const.  Whilst not really a singleton, it is meant to be effectively the entry point.  E.g. the main function will create a new `Game` object and call it's only public method `Run()` and the rest is handled from there.  The derived classes of `Game` would be responsible for any other objects required and shouldn't need access to the game.  I'm probably just overthinking it when I don't need things to be const.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Game::screen` is private, it cannot be accessed by the derived class. While a caller of `GetScreen()` can access the `Screen` object, he cannot modify what the `Game`'s stored `screen` points to. So you're perfectly fine with e.g. providing these two overloads:

```
class Game
{
  Screen *screen;

protected:
  const Screen* GetScreen() const;
  Screen* GetScreen();
};
```

None of them allows the derived class to modify the `screen` pointer itself, so it cannot "reset" it to point somewhere `Game` wouldn't want it to point.

Answer (score -2):

I strongly suggest you update your knowledge of pointers in C++. There is almost no reason to use raw pointers these days.

To answer the question directly, the `Game.GetScreen()` function would want to 'const' differently depending on how exactly you wish for it behave.

If you return a `const Screen*` you are returning a pointer to a Screen object that is constant (cannot be modified). You would normally wish to make such a function const allowing it to be called on a Game object that is const it self.  If somebody has a non-const Game object, you can allow them to get the Screen object that they can then modify by simply returning a `Screen*`.

That said, I return to my opening point, you shouldn't use raw pointers.

Initially, you should just have the Screen object stored by value, and return references, giving you a class along the lines of:

```
Class Game{
    Screen screen;
public:
    const Screen& GetScreen() const{ return screen; }
    Screen& GetScreen(){ return screen; }
};
```

This may look like you are copying the Screen object to return it, but the return types ensure you are returning a reference to the same screen object, rather than a copy.

If you really do need dynamic creation of the Screen object (ie, you cannot create it either before or as you create the Game object) then you should use a `std::unique_ptr<Screen>`. This can be used very much like a raw pointer, but will take care of a lot of the functionality for you. However, you wish to share access to this Screen pointer, so you probably want to use `std::shared_ptr<Screen>` and return `std::weak_ptr<Screen>` from the the get function. The weak_ptr can be used to allow others access, but your initial Game object still *owns* the Screen object.

Long story short, store the Screen object by value, and return references to it.